# Error compiling an OpenCV project with CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS_uQGOQIdg&feature=iv&src_vid=bSeFrPrqZ2A&annotation_id=annotation_3340124015) trying to create some OpenCV project.
It worked great in Windows and Visual Studio but then I tried to run it in my Ubunto VM using CMake by using the following CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( TrackObj )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( TrackObj Source.cpp Fruit.cpp Fruit.h)
target_link_libraries( TrackObj ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

When I run `cmake .` it seems like everything is fine:

```
vm@vm-ubuntu:~/Desktop/TrackObj$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vm/Desktop/TrackObj
```

but when I run `make` I get the following errors:

```
vm@vm-ubuntu:~/Desktop/TrackObj$ make
Scanning dependencies of target TrackObj
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TrackObj.dir/Source.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:35:0,
                 from /home/vm/Desktop/TrackObj/Source.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TrackObj.dir/Source.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TrackObj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm very new to CMake but I'm pretty sure the problem is something with the fact I'm using multiple .cpp files and the way I'm using CMake. The reason is that **when I tried to run a [previews step in the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSeFrPrqZ2A), when the project includes only one .cpp file, it all works great.**

You can see the source code that **did work** [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kylehounslow/opencv-tuts/master/object-tracking-tut/objectTrackingTut.cpp) (with minor changes like removing `#include <opencv\highgui.h> #include <opencv\cv.h>` and writing instead: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`.
And the source code that **did not work** [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kylehounslow/opencv-tuts/master/multiple-object-tracking-tut/part-two/multipleObjectTracking.cpp) with the same minor changes. In addition, the project includes the very simple Fruit.cpp and Fruit.h as described in the video.

I went over the not so friendly [official tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) of CMake and the more friendly [johnlamp](https://www.johnlamp.net/cmake-tutorial-1-getting-started.html) and [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) tutorials but could not find what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you that you need to enable C++11 features for the compiler. You can do this by setting the compiler flag `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` for legacy compilers). In CMake, you define compiler flags in the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`/`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variables, depending on the target language.

In your case:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```